# Color bar anchor widht

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I'm trying to label my colorbar using

```
cbar.set_label('log10(Ha)', rotation=270)
```

but the colorbar numbers and the legend are overlapped like in this image:

[image]

Does anybody have a possible solution for this problem?

Thanks for the help :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use **`labelpad`** to adjust the width between colorbar and its label.
Here is an example, the data which I clipped from [pylab_examples example code: contourf_demo.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html) were omitted to stand out the colorbar.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

ax1  = plt.subplot(121)
cbar1 = plt.colorbar(CS)
cbar1.ax.set_ylabel('verbosity coefficient',labelpad = 15,fontsize = 15)

ax2  = plt.subplot(122)
cbar2 = plt.colorbar(CS)
cbar2.ax.set_ylabel('verbosity coefficient',labelpad = 25,fontsize = 15)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. If it helps, you can accept my answer. :)